# Datasource bean definition in applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, mysql, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am building a Spring MVC Web application. I have created applicationContext.xml file. I am trying to connect to mysql database. But when I define datasource bean in applicationContext.xml the tomcat server starts and it says `404- resource not found`.

If I remove all the beans from the applicationContext.xml the project runs properly.

What am I doing wrong? It is said that datasources should be defined in the applicationContext.xml but is there other way to define datasource?

Here is my **applicationContext.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cinema.repository" />


    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="userDao" class="com.cinema.repository.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties" />
</beans>
```

And this is my **web.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>Cinema Booking</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Can you please point out what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You application probably fails to start. Look at the server-logs of your servlet-container. (eg `TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

san your problem is most likely to be in `<context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties" />` it should be like this `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/jdbc.properties" />` i am assuming that the application can not start because there is an error in the listener (the listener can not find the jdbc.properties)i think that you have put jdbc.properties in your classpath because you probably wont put jdbc.properties in the web folder making it accessible to every one can access to your application